# Semantic UI combine all tags from multiple Dropdown with Multiselection

Tags: jquery, html, css, dropdown, semantic-ui

I am trying to create a complex Filter for a table. I created several dropdown menus with multiselection in Semantic UI. The selected tags are shown inside the dropdown field for every dropdown (Standard Semantic UI Multiselection Dropdown).

Question: Is it possible to collect all the Tags inside a separate Field - no matter which dropdown they have been chosen (see image)?

[Above: 2 Standard Semantic UI Filter // Below: Photoshopped Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC7M8.png)

```
<div class="ui multiple dropdown">
          <input type="hidden" name="filters">
          <i class="filter icon"></i>
          <span class="text">Filter location</span>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="ui icon search input">
              <i class="search icon"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search locations...">
            </div>
              <div class="scrolling menu">
              <div class="item" data-value="important">
                <i class="marker icon"></i>
                Hamburg
              </div>
              <div class="item" data-value="announcement">
                <i class="marker icon"></i>
                Berlin
              </div>
              <div class="item" data-value="cannotfix">
                <i class="marker icon"></i>
                Munich
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
           
        <div class="ui multiple dropdown">
          <input type="hidden" name="filters">
          <i class="filter icon"></i>
          <span class="text">Filter product category</span>
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="ui icon search input">
              <i class="search icon"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search category...">
            </div>
              <div class="scrolling menu">
              <div class="item" data-value="important">
                <i class="sitemap icon"></i>
                Furniture
              </div>
              <div class="item" data-value="announcement">
                <i class="sitemap icon"></i>
                Electronics
              </div>
              <div class="item" data-value="cannotfix">
                <i class="sitemap icon"></i>
                Food
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```